# WebSphere MQ recovery of in-flight messages after failover

Tags: message, ibm-mq, recovery, high-availability, failover

Does WebSphere MQ v7 guarantee the recovery of in-flight messages after failover to a standby queue manager?

If so, how is this accomplished?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are two primary types of standby instances which support this level of recovery.  The first is in a traditional hardware cluster such as Power HA, HACMP, Veritas, MSCS and so forth.  The other is a Multi-Instance Queue Manager (MIQM).  Both of these are capable of running the queue manager on more than one server with data and log files occupying shared disk which is accessible to all instances.

In both cases, persistent messages which have been committed prior to the termination of the primary QMgr will be recovered.  The secondary QMgr will assume possesion of the data and log files during the failover event.  From the perspective of the failover node it is the same as if the QMgr was just starting up after a shutdown or crash, it just hapens to now be running on a different server.

The main differences between a hardware cluster versus MIQM is that a hardware cluster fails over the IP address and possibly non-MQ processes as well.  The MIQM recovers only the MQ processes and comes up on a different IP address.  Applications with V7 clients can be configured with multi-instance connection details to allow for the multiple IP addresses.

So for these solutions in which the state of the QMgr and any in-flight messages is stored on shared disk, bringing the QMgr up with the same shared disk but on a different node recovers the state of the QMgr, including any in-flight messages.